# Classes of functions from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that can be completely determined from a finite interval

Tags: real-analysis

Inspired by Cauchy's integral formula (I've taken complex but not real analysis), for which classses (polynomial, rational, continuous, $C^1$? something else entirely?) of functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the following statement true:

If there exists a pair of real numbers $a$ and $b$, $a < b$, such that for all $x$ in $[a,b]$, $f(x) = g(x)$, then $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

In other words, types of functions such that if we have two functions that are equal on some interval, we can automatically know they are equal on the entire real line.

One easy to prove example is degree one polynomials (lines).

Comment: Works for the class of real analytic functions. And obviously also for the class of periodic functions with period $<b-a$ :-)

Comment: Closely related : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-analytic_function